# Unmet dependencies when installing Mono 3 on XBMCbuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I am trying to install Mono 3 on a 32bit XBMCbuntu 12.10 box. 
I followed the instructions on http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Debian.

I added the line

```
deb http://debian.meebey.net/experimental/mono /
```

to my sources-list via:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then after updating and trying to install i get this:

```
root@XBMC:~/xg# apt-get install mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-2.0-gac (= 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1) but 3.0.6+dfsg-1~exp1~pre1 is to be installed
                 Depends: mono-2.0-service (= 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1) but 3.0.6+dfsg-1~exp1~pre1 is to be installed
                 Depends: monodoc-manual (= 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1) but 3.0.6+dfsg-1~exp1~pre1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do i fix this?